# Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-forms-designer

I have project with Visual Studio 2015 and used Sqlite as back end , I make a simple application to insert value this is my code

```
con.Open();
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1 (Name) VALUES ('First')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
con.Close();
```

But the code is not running it says :

"An unhandled exception of type'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I make too many research over the internet but none of them is not working like (make debugger to Any Debug) , uncheck suppress Jit , but none of them is not fixing my problem.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the SQLite.NET.dll to me. The code you provide looks perfectly ok to me.

Comment: i make download all dll in the official website this once

http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/downloads/

Comment: On which line you get the exception?

Comment: @Dmitry in this line "con.Open();"

Comment: also this is my connection string 

SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = db.sqlite; Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");